# CMFCMenuBar kind of Transparency for a CMFCToolBar

Tags: c++, mfc, toolbar, transparent

I want to let a Toolbar in MFC (`CMFCToolBar`) appear transparent just like the default appearence of a `CMFCMenuBar`.

I'm using the control styles `TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT` when creating the toolbar and do get a transparent background. However, I still have a top and bottom border and the gripper stays the same as well.

`SetBorders(0,0,0,0)` or removing the styles `CBRS_BORDER_TOP | CBRS_BORDER_BOTTOM` won't do the trick.

And using `CCS_NODIVIDER` (for apparently removing the 2px top border) doesn't have an effect either.

I could imagine that a custom `CMFCVisualManager` class might be the way to go (e.g. playing with `CMFCVisualManager::OnFillBarBackground`), but couldn't figure anything out yet regarding that.

To be clear, this is the code I currently have:

```
m_wndToolBar.CreateEx(this /*MainFrame*/, TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT,
                      WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_ALIGN_TOP)
LoadToolBar(IDR_MY_TOOLBAR, 0, 0, TRUE);
m_wndToolBar.SetPaneStyle(GetPaneStyle() & ~(CBRS_BORDER_TOP    |
                                             CBRS_BORDER_BOTTOM |
                                             CBRS_BORDER_LEFT   |
                                             CBRS_BORDER_RIGHT));
m_wndToolBar.SetBorders(0,0,0,0);
```

Here's where I am right now:

[image]

And this is my goal:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try removing `CBRS_GRIPPER`? Consider posting in your question the actual code that you're using to create/modify the toolbar.

Comment: I don't want to remove the gripper, I would just like to have it appear the same way it does with the CMFCMenuBar, i.e. transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `SetExclusiveRowMode(true)`? Menu bars have exclusive row mode set, toolbars don't by default.

Comment: Yes, in fact I do have exclusive row mode set to true, that works all fine, but it doesn't change anything regarding the transparency.